# jqplot number of the week of the year

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm trying to show the number of the week of the year on the xAxis, so this my code but it's not working

```
$.jqplot('my_canvas' + id, data, {
    title: 'Graphic',
    xaxis: {
            renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            min: from_date,
            label: "WEEK",
            tickInterval: '1 week',
            tickOptions:{
                formatter: Formatter   //why formatter is not not being called?
            }                

        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: maximum_value
        }
        highlighter: {
           show: true
    }
}



Formatter = function (format, val) {    
    return numberOftheWeek(val);
}
```

formatter is not being called when using **renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer** but when i use **renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer.** it's called but all the aAxis labels are superimposed.

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this ,not sure whether it works or not:

```
 xaxis: { 
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            label: "WEEK",
            min:  from_date,

            tickInterval: '1 WEEK',
            tickOptions: {formatString:Formatter, markSize: 4},


            },
```

Comment: It doest not works.. raise this error!! 
TypeError: ab.match is not a function

...=1/6*(an[1]-an[0])/ao(ae[af],ae[af-1]);ak=1/2*(ae[af]*an[0]-ae[af-1]*an[1])/ao(a...

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: jqplot Version: 1.0.0b2_r1012
----jquery 1.7.1----

Comment: i m using jqplot version:1.0.0b2_r1012...may be version could be the problem...add this line in the start in script tag..<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>